# ElasticSearch / tire histogram usage, how to return certain values from basket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use histogram. I have a price field in my model and I want to group results with some interval for example in 400 units. Page should have links: 400, 800, 1200, 1600. On clicking link results should be filtered with this price group.(Same thing with dates)
In model I have:

```
def self.search params
      tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
        query do
          boolean do
           ...
            must { term :price, params[:price] } if params[:price].present?
            must { term :date_from, params[:dates]   } if params[:dates].present?
          end
        end


        facet("prices")       {  histogram :price, interval: 400, order: 'key'  }
        facet('dates')       {  date :date_from, interval: '3w', order: 'time'}
      end
    end
```

It gives me right facets:

> {"_type"=>"histogram", "entries"=>[{"key"=>600, "count"=>20},
>   {"key"=>1800, "count"=>30}]}

but how can I  use it with params?  My implementation gives me only one field with exact match. I'll be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

After making some research (a lot), I realized that the only way of getting range of values is "range"  with gt/gte/lt/lte 
(http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)

So answer on my own question is:

```
must { range :price, gte: params[:price], lt: params[:price].to_i + 400  } if params[:price].present?
must { range :date_from, gte: params[:dates], lt: Time.at(params[:dates].to_i / 1000) + 3.weeks   } if params[:dates].present?
```